# Python:'list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'

Tags: python

I have a xml parser that parses through code and gives me a nested list (I hope) with lists of title and page:

```
if name == 'page':
    self._pages.append((self._values['title'], self._values['text']))
```

I want to cicle through this nested list to find certain strings. But my loop gives me an error

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

loop:

```
for e in handler._pages:
    title = mwparserfromhell.parse(handler._pages[e][0])
```

Edit:
I defined _pages in my class contant handler as follows:

```
class WikisourceXmlHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.__init__(self)
        self._buffer = None
        self._current_tag = None
        self._values = {}
        self._pages = []
```

Based on the trail set up by John I came up with:

```
title = mwparserfromhell.parse(handler._pages[e][0]) 
page = mwparserfromhell.parse(handler._pages) title = page[0]
```

but then I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: If `e` is an *element* of `handler._pages`, how does `handler._pages[e]` make any sense?

Comment: You want to include more code so that people answering your question can execute the code. In this case you have not defined `handler._pages` is this a list? I can only infer that you actually want a `dict`

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell, your `self._pages` is a list of tuples. In your for loop then, `e` is an element in the list, not an index. It's hard to tell from the incomplete picture, but I think you want this:

```
for e in handler._pages:
    title = mwparserfromhell.parse(e[0])
```